# Como executar um método automaticamente fora do onCreate() da Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Tenho uma *MainActivity* que possui **4** botões, quando o usuário seleciona algum deles, o método do botão chama outra *Activity*, que exibirá uma consulta feita num *XML* em um *ListView* dessa nova *Activity*. Estou fazendo assim:

Método `onCreate` da nova *Activity*:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.refeicaoview);
        lstDados = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstDados);
        adpItens = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_lista);
        lstDados.setAdapter(adpItens);
        iniciaBusca(); //este método faz a consulta ao XML e retorna os dados para serem exibidos na listView acima
}
```

O que eu percebo é que dessa maneira, quando se clica no botão na *MainActivity*, ele demora para criar a nova *Activity*, pois imagino que execute o `iniciaBusca()` primeiro, carregue o *listView* para depois exibir a tela.

O que eu quero é que a tela seja criada, e esse método `iniciaBusca()` inicie em seguida, e enquanto ele executa, aparecer um *progressDialog* na interface para o usuário.

Alguém tem uma dica? Solução? :D

Consegui. ;)

Comment: Pode usar uma `AsyncTask` na sua "nova" _Activity_ e executar este método dentro dela e adicionar o seu _progressDialog_!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o @IgorMello disse,você deverá usar uma [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Basicamente, o que um *Async Task* faz é executar um código em uma thread diferente da *UIThread*, que é thread principal e é responsável pela construção das activities. Dessa maneira, é possível executar um código em segundo plano enquanto a activity carrega normalmente, evitando o "congelamento" da mesma.

A classe *Async Task* possui 3 métodos importantes que são executados nessa ordem:

1. **onPreExecute** : chamado antes que a tarefa de longa duração seja executada. Geralmente é utilizada para mostrar um progress bar.
2. **doInBackground** : realiza uma tarefa de longa duração ( acesso a um  BD local ou externo ) .

   **Atenção:** *Dentro deste método não devem ser feitos acessos a elementos da view, caso isso seja feito, você receberá um erro do tipo* **java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"**

   Se você quiser manipular a view, você deve usar os métodos  `onPreExecute()` e `onPostExecute()`

   Se realmente for necessário acessar a view dentro do método `doInBackground()` coloque o método de acesso a view dentro do método `runOnUiThread()` e coloque-o dentro do `doInBackground()`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... parametros) {

       // Realiza tarefa de longa duração ...

       // Acessa a view
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

           public void run() {

               // faça o acesso a view aqui
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. **onPostExecute** : chamado assim que a tarefa de longa duração é concluída. É utilizada para acessar e tratar a variável de retorno da tarefa de longa duração

Assim,para implementar um *Async Task* , você pode colocar o seguinte código na sua activity

```
private class ConsultaXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // Código para mostrar o progress bar
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... parametros) {

      // Código que realiza a consulta de um arquivoXML
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String arquivoXML) {

      // Código que será executado quando o XML for obtido
      // No seu caso, você para de mostrar o progress bar
      // e mostra o arquivoXML na tela
    }
}
```

Em seguinda, no `onCreate()` da sua activity, após criar os views, faça

```
ConsultaXML consulta = new ConsultaXML();
consulta.execute("");
```

Comment: Obrigado @regmoraes, vou fazer aqui para ver se assim resolve o meu problema. ;)

Comment: Toda vez que tento colocar threads aparece essa mensagem "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". O que eu faço? :S

Comment: @RobledoGomes, eu editei a resposta com a solução para esse problema, dê uma olhada

Comment: Ei @regmoraes eu coloquei a parte do código que faz a busca no XML, dá uma olhada por favor... :D

Comment: Eu consegui @regmoraes, com a sua ajuda e um vídeo do YouTube deu certo. Agora a Activity é iniciada, o progress aparece e a busca é feita.